# Weblogic Store and Forward and why it doesn't try to send stored messages?

Tags: weblogic

I have local Weblogic with SAF configuration.

The destination is down and I see in logs (logs/safagents/ContentEngineSAF/**jms.messages.log**) that some messages I sent are **Stored** and **Expired** after less than 100ms.

When the destination is up and running, those stored messages are not forwarded at all. Where to look in Weblogic why messages are not forward?

Which part of a configuration is responsible for this behaviour:

Store -> Try to Forward (I don't have this in log) -> Expire -> Try to Forward again -> Expire -> Try to Forward again -> Forward

In the log I have only Store and Expire information for JMS message or Store and Forward.

In SAF Agents, Time-To-Live is 0, which means when messages are in Current state, it should be there forever until it is Forwarded (consumed), I guess.

But in JMS module, myJMSSystewmResource, mySAFImportedDestination/Queues/myQueue, there is **SAF Default Time-to-Live: 100**. I guess here configuration if failed after 100ms, go to expired and deleted from Store, right?

So, to be forever until a successful forward message, should be 0 or -1?

**EDITED**

When a message is Expired, it means it is deleted from Store, so this is the reason why it is not sent again.

That's why I implemented SAF Error Handling, and now there is no Expired or Removed messages, but still, some messages are just Stored but they are not Forwarded.

Should I change Time-to-Live value, and how, 0, -1 or some bigger number than 100ms?

Comment: I have the same issue. Have you solved this?

Answer (score 0):

This is oracle description for saf agent time to live:

The default amount of time, in milliseconds, that the agent guarantees to reliably send messages.
A value of 0 means the agent guarantees to reliably send messages for the duration of the conversation.
Updating DefaultTimeToLive causes conversations starting after the update to use the new value.
MBean Attribute:
SAFAgentMBean.DefaultTimeToLive
Minimum value: 0

And these are the reason why saf agents miss delivery of messages:

```
Network outage
The endpoint does not exist (not configured)
The endpoint is down
Endpoint quota failure
Security denial
Required QOS is not supported
The WSRM conversation times out (the conversation is idle for too long).
```

Take a look at the imported destinations on the other side of your sending saf agent.

Comment: 'A value of 0 means the agent guarantees to reliably send messages for the duration of the conversation.' - please, explain this, what is 'the duration of the conversation'?
And what if it is -1?
Further, I have a clustered environment (3 nodes) and for SAF do I need 3 JMS servers for each node?
I don't understand after failure to send a message, why it doesn't try to resend from time to time? Because I don't have JMS servers?

Answer (score 0):

Recently I have faced a similar issue as well: In case of communication error SAF just "forgot" to deliver the message to the destination JMS.

In my case, I have seen the problem clearly in the WebLogic log but after WL logged the problem, it lost the message:

```
<Aug 8, 2022 4:47:54,331 PM CEST> <Info> <JMS> <BEA-040410> <FailedJMSMessage for store-and-forward: JMSMessageID='ID:<932349.1659970073992.0>' >
 <HeaderFields JMSCorrelationID='...'
    JMSDeliveryMode='PERSISTENT'
    JMSDeliveryTime='Mon Aug 08 16:47:53 CEST 2022'
    JMSDestination=null
    JMSExpiration='Thu Jan 01 01:00:00 CET 1970'
    JMSPriority='4'
    JMSRedelivered='false'
    JMSRedeliveryLimit='2147483647'
    JMSReplyTo=null
    JMSTimestamp='Mon Aug 08 16:47:53 CEST 2022'
    JMSType=null />
 </FailedJMSMessage>
```

The reason why that happened is that the `SAF Error Handling` was set to `Log`. According to [this Oracle doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/middleware/fusion-middleware/weblogic-server/12.2.1.4/safmg/administering-store-and-forward-service-oracle-weblogic-server.pdf), this is the normal behavior of the `Log` setting.

To solve the delivery/re-delivery issue you must review and configure your SAF components properly, based on the mentioned Oracle doc:

- Persistent store
- SAF Agent
- JMS Server
- JMS module
- Connection Factory
- SAF Imported Destination
- SAF Error Handler

Especially the last one: `SAF Error Handler`